# Radii of Neighborhoods with non-Real Distance Metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here is the definition of a neighborhood in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*:

> A *neighborhood* of $p$ is a set $N_r (p)$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p, q) < r$, for some $r>0$. The number $r$ is called the *radius* of $N_r (p)$

Now, it is not explicitly stated that $r \in \mathbb{R}$, however in exercise 10 of Chapter 2, he states asks about the compactness of an infinite metric space whose distance function is defined as

> $d(p, q) = 1$ if $p \neq q$
>
> $d(p, q) = 0$ if $p = q$

One's response to the compactness as well as closed-ness and openness of subsets of this space seems then to depend on whether $r$ can be any $\mathbb{R}$ between 0 and 1, or whether it is confined to be a value in the set of possible distances - **but how would it even make sense to place $r$ as a distance which cannot exist?** It seems like overlaying a metric function whose image is indeed $\mathbb{R}$ on top of the discrete one, but maybe I am too insistent on the geometry.

I suspect he does mean any real number, since any neighborhood is open, and any finite set is closed.

Additionally, to prove the following theorem by contradiction, he uses some notion of finite, yet open neighborhoods, which seems impossible to create. How can he do this?

> If E is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$.
>
> Proof If no point of $K$ were a limit point of $E$, then each $q \in K$ would have a neighborhood $V_q$ which contains at most one point of $E$ (namely $q$, if $q \in E$). It is clear that no finite subcollection of $\{V_q\}$ can cover $E$ and the same is true of $K$, since $E \subset K$. This contradicts the compactness of $K$.

Comment: Since the relation $>$ is only defined on $\mathbb R$, saying $r>0$ also implies that $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: +1 for listening to user input and improving your question. It's much nicer to read now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first comment:

> Now, it is not explicitly stated that $r \in \mathbb{R}$,

True, it is not **explicitly** stated, however since it is stated that $r>0$, and $>$ is a relation defined on $\mathbb R$, it is **implicitly** stated that $r\in\mathbb R$.

---

Second comment:

> One's response to the compactness as well as closed-ness and openness of subsets of this space seems then to depend on whether $r$ can be any $\mathbb{R}$ between 0 and 1, or whether it is confined to be a value in the set of possible distances

True, if you were allowed to change the range from which $r$ can be selected, then the closedness of sets would change. But, alas, you are **not** allowed to change the range. When speaking of neighborhoods, $r$ can **always** be any positive real number. That's the definition of neighborhoods. If you restrict $r$, then you aren't making a mistake, really, but what you are then talking about are no longer neighborhoods. You can call those things whatever else you want (for all I care, call them fluffy cushions), but the word neighborhood is taken.

---

Third comment:

> **but how would it even make sense to place $r$ as a distance which cannot exist?**

Why not? We can perfectly well define the set $\{x\in X: d(x_0, x) < 10\}$ even though the maximum distance we can reach is $1$. Sure, the set will be the same as the set $${x\in X: d(x_0, x) < 100}$, but why do you think this is somehow wrong? I can perfectly well speak of "the set of all humans that are shorter than 15 meters", and sure, this is a redundant way of speaking (since this set is the same as the set of all humans), but it is not **wrong**. It's a perfectly well defined set.

---

Fourth:

> and any finite set is closed.

This is false in general. It is possible to define a topology in which finite sets are not closed. However, it is true in metric spaces.

---

Fifth:

> Additionally, to prove the following theorem by contradiction, he uses some contrived notion of finite, yet open neighborhoods.

Calling an argument "contrived" is not a mathematical argument, so I cannot really comment on that. The proof you cite is mathematically rigorous and correct, and you calling it names doesn't change the correctness of the underlying mathematics.

In fact, your comment shows a clear misunderstanding of the proof, since Rudin himself does not speak of **finite** neighborhoods anywhere in the proof. Each set $V_q$ is a neighborhood, and depending on the metric it **can** be finite, but in the case of a Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^n$, the set $V_q$ is infinite.

Comment: By posting on Stackexchange, it is clear I am trying to understand better. I was not actually attacking Rudin or his argument, but trying to understand why. My use of words like contrived is to show where my current understanding is currently. If I did not use words like that, it would be difficult to see where the issue is.

Comment: @Krpcannon Then take my annoyance as a comment on your word choice. There are word choices that express confusion (phrases like "I don't understand why...", "It is unclear why", "I am confused by..."), but you did not use them. Saying "This is contrived" does not tell me "I don't understand this". It tells me "I think I understand this and it is BS".

Comment: Ahh so my fault was in embedding a metric space into the discussion when there was not any! Thanks a lot. The fact that we can indeed define metric spaces to contain finite neighborhoods around points seems to be what derailed me with the theorem and is probably what has messed up the rest of the chapter also.

Comment: @Krpcannon I don't know what you mean by "embedding a metric space". There is definitelly talk about metric spaces here, so I don't see why you think that's a mistake though. I don't really know what your mistake is, but your refusal to accept that finite open neighborhoods can exist may be one of them.

Comment: It was becuase of the following lines from the text: "every neighborhood is an open set", and the remark that a finite set is closed - that's why I thought it was contradictory to create a finite neighborhood - but as you mentioned not all finite sets are closed, so I was 'embedding' a metric space into the theorem for which neighborhoods could not be finite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66585/discussion-between-krpcannon-and-5xum).

Comment: Sets are not doors, they can be open and closed at the same time. For example, in the discrete topology literally every subset is open, and as a consequence, every subset is also closed.

Answer (score 0):

> but how would it even make sense to place r as a distance which cannot exist?

There is no issue here. Even in the metric you've given, the so called discrete metric, you can ask about $N_{1/2}(p)$. We have $N_{1/2}(p) = \{x\in X: d(p,x)<1/2\}=\{p\}$ since all other points $x\neq p$ in $X$ will give $d(p,x)=1>1/2$.

> It seems to be a weak point, not a feature, of this mathematical genus that we can invent impossible, ontologically unsound things to prove a point, such as finite neighborhoods.

Calm down, there is nothing wrong with what Rudin has written, topology can be counter intuitive but it's not ontologically unsound. A neighborhood can consist of a single point, as we have just shown above. Think about the definition of limit point and what it would mean to NOT be a limit point. This should help you understand why there would have to be a neighborhood of each point with at most one point from $E$ (Because if such a neighborhood does not exist then ____).

Comment: You read hostility when I did not write any. Thanks for your response. I did not write any obscenities nor did I insult or offend anyone.

Comment: You absolutely did use hostile language. Maybe your intent was not to come across as hostile, but if that's the case your language betrayed you. Specifically this sentence,

"It seems to be a weak point, not a feature, of this mathematical genus that we can invent impossible, ontologically unsound things to prove a point, such as finite neighborhoods."

I'm obviously not the only one who read your post this way, maybe be more careful with how you write next time. Or ignore the criticism and just take the hints provided, it's not like I withheld assistance because I disagree with your words

Comment: I would doubt I am alone in wondering whether or not there was another way of approaching it.

Comment: Here is what you could have written, "To me this seems impossible, can someone explain how a neighborhood can be finite".

Comment: Your input on the changes would be appreciated.

Comment: Theyre good changes. Do you feel like question has been answered or are you still feeling stuck?

Comment: Yes I believe the ball is in my court now in terms of work to do. Thanks.